# Is there a correct way of taking a histogram of ratios?

Tags: matlab, math, statistics, histogram

My problem is as follows;  I have two vectors `u` and `v`.  I have computed a table of cross-ratios like so:

```
[ u1/v1, u1/v2, u1/v3, u1/v4, ... ]
[ u2/v1, u2/v2, u1/v3, u2/v4, ... ]
[ u3/v1, u3/v2, u1/v3, u3/v4, ... ]
[ u4/v1, u4/v2, u1/v3, u4/v4, ... ]
[ ...
```

My task now is to compute a histogram of these cross ratios.  However, it is clear that using linear histogram bins would not make sense - any ratios below 1 would have a far lower sample resolution than the ratios above 1, and the long-tailed nature of the ratio distribution means that my choice of bins would be skewed heavily by large values.

So, my question is: is there a 'correct', or at least better, choice of histogram bins (or equivalently, a transformation to apply to the data) for this situation?  I can see that the  [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) might be relevant although I'm quite sure how.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered plotting the histogram of the log of the ratio? This works as long as your values are strictly positive, and has the nice property that log(u1/v1) = -log(v1/u1).

Comment: @AdamBowen - in that case, I suggest two things: (1) use `reallog` instead of `log` - should be faster. (2) compute `reallog(u)-reallog(v)` instead of `reallog(u/v)`, again, should be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @AdamBowen, that property exactly sums up what I was looking for!  If you were to submit that as an answer I will happily accept it as correct.

Comment: Also thanks @Shai for your comments, I will keep them in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try plotting the histogram of the log of the ratios. This works as long as your values are strictly positive, and has the nice property that log(u1/v1) = -log(v1/u1).

Answer (score 0):

You may calibrate the histogram's bins manually using `histc`.